# Unable to get correct response page using requests library

Tags: python, get, scrapy, request

I am trying to parse the comments present on webpage https://xueqiu.com/S/SZ300816.
But I am not able to get it correctly through request library:

```
>>> url = 'https://xueqiu.com/S/SZ300816'
>>> headers
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}
>>> response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
>>> soup = bs4(response.text)
>>> soup.findAll('article', {'class': "timeline__item"})
[]
>>>
```

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is the behavior you are expecting? What is the actual behavior? Have you looked at the text of the response to verify that there is an element with a class of `timeline__item`? (note that in your code there are two underscores in the class name)

Comment: The response doesn't include <article> elements, but they are in the page loaded by chrome. Usually this means that javascript is filling it in. Instead of requests, you could use selenium to open a browser and get the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the url from the network tab of chrome devlopment tool. data loaded via from this url in json format. I try to resolve your problem, hope help you.

```
  from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    import requests
    import json
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
    }
    def scrape(url):
        with requests.Session() as req:
            req.headers.update(headers)
            r = req.get(url)
            mydata =r.json()
            print(mydata['list'][0])
            print(mydata['list'][0]['text'])
            print(mydata['list'][0]['description'])
    
           
    url =  'https://xueqiu.com/query/v1/symbol/search/status?u=141606248084627&uuid=1331335789820403712&count=10&comment=0&symbol=SZ300816&hl=0&source=all&sort=&page=1&q=&type=11&session_token=null&access_token=db48cfe87b71562f38e03269b22f459d974aa8ae'
    scrape(url)
```

Comment: But the access token present is url is not constant, can you suggest a way how to extract is automaticaly?

Comment: Thanks. Which token are you talking about?

Comment: The url you posted in the answer contains this param access_token=db48cfe87b71562f38e03269b22f459d974aa8ae, I am talkin about this access token.

Comment: You can get it print(r.request.path_url.split('&')[-1]) command.  I got url from network tab through inspect . here is details https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-location/#:~:text=To%20check%20this%20Location%20in,Google%20Chrome . acces_token in location tab in response headers.